# Lookup based on several columns

Tags: r, lookup

I have a data frame that looks like this (of course it is way bigger):

```
> df1
# A tibble: 10 x 4
    index1 index2      date1      date2
     <int>  <int>     <date>     <date>
 1 5800032      6 2012-07-02 2013-09-18
 2 5800032      7 2013-09-18 1970-01-01
 3 5800254      6 2013-01-04 1970-01-01
 4 5800261      5 2012-01-23 2013-02-11
 5 5800261      6 2013-02-11 2014-02-05
 6 5800261      7 2014-02-05 1970-01-01
 7 3002704      7 2012-01-23 1970-01-01
 8 3002728      7 2012-10-20 1970-01-01
 9 3002810      7 2012-07-18 1970-01-01
10 8504593      3 2012-01-11 1970-01-01
```

The original variables are: `index1`, `index2` and `date1`. There is one or more records with the same `index1` value (their sequence is determined by `index2`). My objective is to filter out intervals between consequent values of `date1` for the same value of `index1`. This means that there must be at least two records with the same `index1` value to create an interval.
So I created `date2` variable that provides the end date of the interval that starts on `date1`. This simply equals `date1` of the consequent record (`date2[n] = date1[n+1]`). If `date1[n]` is the latest (or the only) date for the given `index1` value, then `date2[n] <- 0`.

I couldn't come up with a better idea than ordering the `df` by `index1` and `index2` and running a for loop:

```
for (i in 1:(nrow(df1)-1)){
  if (df1$index1[i] == df1$index1[i+1]){
    df1$date2[i] <- df1$date1[i+1]
  }
  else{df1$date2[i] <- 0}
}
```

It sort of worked, but it was visibly slow and for some reason it did not "find" all values it should have. Also, I'm sure there must be a much more intelligent way of doing this task - possibly with `sapply` function. Any ideas are appreciated!

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but perhaps using `dplyr` will help group and filter. For example, `require(dplyr); df1 %>% group_by(index1) %>% arrange(index2)` will group the indexes together and arrange within each group by index2. I'll need to better understand what you want before I can do more.

Comment: Thanks! Trying to explain: what I have in date1 column is a list of date points, but what I need is to define the intervals between these date points for the same index1 value, so I need to add the end date of the interval to data2 column. First interval is between date1[min] and date1[min+1], second interval is between date1[min+1] and date1[min+2] and so on. End date for the interval starting at date1[n] is date2[n], that equals date1[n+1].  If there is only one record for a given index1 value, then date2 = 0, because two date points are needed for an interval. Same with data1[max].

Comment: If you actually want to show a zero, you will need to convert `date1` to something like a character since each column of a data frame must be of the same type: `df1 %>% 
  group_by(index1) %>% 
  arrange(index2) %>%
  mutate(date1 = as.character(date1)) %>%
  mutate(date2 = lag(date1, default = "0"))` give you actual zeros.

Comment: Great! Only that I needed to use `lead` instead of `lag`. Works perfectly, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can create date2 using lag from dplyr

```
    df1 %>% 
    group_by(index1) %>% 
    arrange(index2) %>%
    mutate(date2 = lag(date1, default=0))
```

I didn't clearly understand the filtering part of your question. Your problem may have to do with filtering on default date (1970-01-01) (value = zero)